# Nginx disable url rewrite for specific path / url

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following nginx configuration for the url rewrite

```
location / { ##merge
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location /devtools/phpmyadmin/ { ##merge
    root /var/www/domain.tld/web;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

in the `/var/www/domain.tld/web/` directory have an `/api/` directory and I want disable for the url rewrite for this. So if I woud like access from url with `index.php`: `http://domain.tld/api/index.php/function/method`

How can I modify the nginx config file?

---

**Edit:**

I try the following rewrite, but not working:

```
location = /api {
    rewrite ^ /api/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Is there a `root` directive above the first `location` block? Do you have a `location ~ \.php$` block at the `server` block level?

Comment: @RichardSmith No root directive above the first location block and the other question is no - I edit the nginx config from ispconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confess that I do not understand your configuration file. Generally, you would define a `root` to be inherited by all (or most) of your `location` blocks. And usually a separate `location ~ \.php$` block to handle off-loading `.php` scripts to a PHP processor via FastCGI.

Ignoring your `location /devtools/phpmyadmin/` block for the moment, a typical implementation would look like this:

```
root /var/www/domain.tld/web;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

The `nginx` directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).

If you want URIs that begin with `/api` to use a different controller, you could add:

```
location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;
}
```

I cannot see the purpose of the `location /devtools/phpmyadmin/` block, as it does not seem to add any more functionality.